# how to convert one image to a video by using ffmpeg?

Tags: image-processing, terminal, ffmpeg

I downloaded and installed ffmpeg on my mac, however, I have a problem using it. I tried to use

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i rho1.png -c:v libx264 -t 15 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=320:240 out.mp4
```

however, the output is

```
ld: warning: ignoring file video, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x66 0x66 0x6D 0x70 0x65 0x67 0x20 0x2D 0x6C 0x6F 0x6F 0x70 0x20 0x31 0x20 0x2D ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): video
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_main", referenced from:
 implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Need help with creating a video by using one picture in png.

Comment: How did you install ffmpeg exactly?

Comment: just follow instructions on this website: http://ericholsinger.com/install-ffmpeg-on-a-mac

Comment: Try with `brew install ffmpeg`

Comment: it says that it was already been installed. I am not sure in which program language should I use ffmpeg. Should it be C or any other?

Comment: are you using the command line tool or the libs? `ffmpeg` is ISO C90 plus some stuff from ISO C99

Comment: what I did is I created a C file, included <stdio.h> library and used the code above, ffmpeg -loop 1 -i rho1.png -c:v libx264 -t 15 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=320:240 out.mp4. However, I am getting that error. Is my code wrong?

Comment: in this case could you post the relevant code?